# Custom formatting in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, format, cells

I have the following problem in excel.

Lets say I have 10 cells in my spread sheet that contains the following;

```
Cash per 30.06.17
```

I want to use the Concatenate-formula (or other if that solves my problem) in order to be able to use a referance cell to change the date going forward in all 10 cells.

```
=concatenate("Cash per";"referance cell that contains the date)
```

However, when doing this I receive the following;
`Cash per 42916`.

Can somebody help me with this problem? The way I see it I need a special input to the custom category in cells formatting.

Thank you.

Andreas

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the "TEXT"-function to your formula to format the date:

```
=CONCATENATE("Cash per";TEXT([Reference cell with date];"dd.mm.yyyy"))
```